# Grails 2.3.2 not working

Tags: grails

Good morning,
I created a new project with

- Grails 2.3.2
- Java JDK 1.7.0_45

When I run the command:

```
grails run-app
```

see the following errors:

```
**| Configuring classpath
nov 09, 2013 1:52:27 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
| Running Grails application
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
Exception in thread "main"
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error**
```

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: The error is ASM related. If not the project is fresh new, post a portion of your code please.

Comment: I got the same error when running test-app.  The tests would run, but I would still get this error.  @Sana's answer fixed it as well.

Answer (score 17):

Just tried with exact same setup, as you have.

1. Comment-out lines inside of grails.project.fork=[-----]
2. Delete .grails in user's home directory
3. grails clean
4. grails run-app

Its worked for newly created app but surely there are some problems in asm libraries.

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue with the same JDK and same version of Grails. I was pretty happy to see this thread. Could you clairfy #1 for me? I'm not sure which file or what/where I should comment something out. Cheers.

Comment: I've figured it out, it's inside of your_project\grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy :)

Answer (score 3):

Just comment-out section **grails.project.fork** of **BuildConfig.groovy**

That's it.
The error will run away.

Answer (score 1):

For me help adding in BuildConfig.groovy

```
build "org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11"
```

More information on http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10756?focusedCommentId=78003&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

Just remove **grails.project.fork** then **clean-app** and **run-app**.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps which work for me:-

- Delete .grails in user's home directory
- Right click on icon IntelliJ IDE and run as administrator

Hope your problem will be solved.