# Grails 'java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED' error

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

When I am trying to start my Grails application (using `grails run-app` or through GGTS) I have suddenly started getting the following error:

```
| Running Grails application
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
Exception in thread "main"
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I saw the answer to another StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877148/614418) that said to comment out `grails.project.fork` inside my `BuildConfig.groovy` file. While this seems to solve the problem I am still new to Grails so I'm not sure I fully understand what is going on. So, my questions are:

1. Why would my application suddenly start breaking in this way. As far as I know I've not changed anything that would cause this kind of error. I have been developing and running on the same code on another machine all week with no issue. It wasn't until I updated on my desktop that I started seeing this error.
2. What are the settings being commented out used for? It looks like it is setting some JVM parameters. Is this just used to configure memory, etc when using `grails run-app`? I assume these settings would have no effect when I build a WAR and deploy to a tomcat instance later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I found [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.grails.user/146613). Graeme Rocher said that:

> There is an issue with 2.3.2 on Windows only, we plan to address it
>   with a 2.3.3 this week
>
> In the meantime please use 2.3.1 or wait for 2.3.3 this week or follow
>   the instructions in this issue for a workaround:
>
> http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10756

Comment: Ah interesting, I suppose that makes sense why I didn't see the error on my Mac. Guess I will leave the stuff commented out until 2.3.3 then try re-enabling it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I just got this on a Mac (2.3.2, Mountain Lion)