# Grails 2.3.2 GGTS 3.5 not working in debug

Tags: grails

I created a new project with

- Grails 2.3.2
- Java JDK 1.7.0_45
- GGTS 3.4

When trying to run project *after fixing `BuildConfig.groovy`* following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876256/grails-2-3-2-not-working), it's running OK.

However when trying to **debug** the project I am getting the following error:

> *There was an error loading the BuildConfig: argument type mismatch (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)*

In `BuildConfig.groovy` I have the following "fixed" section:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    //test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    //run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    //war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    //console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in grails version 2.3.4.